# VB Forms, filling out a dataset with two SELECT statements

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataset

I'm working on a school project.

I have a problem filling a dataset with 2 SELECT Queries

```
   sql = "SELECT PhoneNo, Forename, Surname, Address, Postcode FROM tblCustomerInfo"
    Conn.Open()
    da1 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Conn)
    'initialises connection with the database and runs sql statement 
    da1.Fill(ds1, "Order")

    sql = "SELECT OrderNo, Total, OrderDate, OrderTime FROM tblOrder"
    da2 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Conn)
    'initialises connection with the database and runs sql statement 
    da2.Fill(ds1, "Order")

    MaxRows = ds1.Tables("Order").Rows.Count
    count = -1

    Label1.Text = ds1.Tables("Order").Rows(0).Item(5)
```

> ```
>  Label1.Text = ds1.Tables("Order").Rows(0).Item(5)
> ```
>
> is to test for the second dataset, however I'm running into a "dbnull" error.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Edit: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.
Exception Detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to combine the two SQL statements into one, separating by semi colon. Then run that query using single DataAdapter. You will probably get it. I didn't test it. But it should work.

Comment: sql = "SELECT PhoneNo, Forename, Surname, Address, Postcode FROM tblCustomerInfo; SELECT OrderNo, Total, OrderDate, OrderTime FROM tblOrder"

I get the following error, Characters found after end of SQL statement.

Comment: Why are you selecting to same DataTable "order"? Use different one so that the schema of the existing table "order" will go in conflict when you try to select the second statement to the same DataTable in the DataSet. FYI: I am a C# developer, I am using your code after converting to C#. Here

Comment: The solution is to  assign label1 to a value in my second dataset, That was pretty slow of me. Sorry, but thanks for making me think about my error. @Ananthan Unni

Answer (score 0):

I normally perform queries like this in ASP.Net VB using the `System.Data.SqlClient` library (i.e., I use SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and SqlDataAdapter instead of OleDb), but assuming it works the same way, I can tell you what I think I see is wrong.

Change

```
Label1.Text = ds1.Tables("Order").Rows(0).Item(5)
```

To

```
Label1.Text = ds1.Tables("Order").Rows(0)(5)
```

---

Although, I normally define a variable for the row first since it makes it easier to loop through and reference various column names. Something like this...

```
Dim r as DataRow = ds1.Tables("Order").Rows(0)
Label1.Text = r("column/field name") 'I'm sure you can use an index number instead of the field name, but I normally just reference the field name, so I may be mistaken.
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that some of the records have null values.  The Dataset Item's collection is a 0 based index, so to check for the fifth field (you only have five in your select statement), you'd likely have to use ".Rows(0).Item(4)".  If you have null values in your records, do a check for it...

```
If Not ds1.Tables("Order").Rows(0).Item(4) Is DBNull.Value Then

     Label1.Text = ds1.Tables("Order").Rows(0).Item(4).ToString()

End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however there shouldn't be a null value in the first place. I managed to solve the issue.